# Maximum update depth exceeded from Navigate component react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom v6` to control the route of my React Js app.

**Here are the specifications:**

1. I'm creating the `AuthenticationRoute` and `PrivateRoute` components.
2. The `AuthenticationRoute` component is used to wrap pages that the user doesn't need to authenticate for examples `SignIn`, `SignUp`, `ForgotPassword`, and `ResetPassword` pages.
3. The `PrivateRoute` component is used to wrap private pages (authentication is needed) for example Home page. Inside the `PrivateRoute`, there are some layouts. One of them is called the `Dashboard` layout to wrap the `Drawer` (Sidebar/Navigation) component and the `Home` page.
4. If the user has not logged in via the `SignIn` page, the app would return the `SignIn` page.
   If the user has logged in, the app would return the `Home` page.

**Here are the current conditions:**

Note: The check sign (✅) represents the conditions I want while the cross sign (❌) represents the error or unwanted conditions.

1. All of the specifications above are met. ✅
2. The first time user runs the app, the `SignIn` page is returned because the user has not logged in. ✅
3. If the user has not logged in and typed "/" route to the address bar (to access the `Home` page) via the `SignIn` page, the app will not redirect the user to the `Home` page instead of returning the `SignIn` page. ✅
4. If the user successfully logged in via the `SignIn` page, the app would return the `Home` page (with "/" route). ✅
5. If the user has logged in and typed "/sign-in" route to the address bar (to access the `SignIn` page) via the `Home` page, the app return error: ❌

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at Navigate (https://5xxrw.csb.app/node_modules/react-router/index.js:247:12)
    at AuthenticationRoute (https://5xxrw.csb.app/src/components/Routes/AuthenticationRoute.jsx:21:26)
    at Routes (https://5xxrw.csb.app/node_modules/react-router/index.js:306:18)
    at App
    at Router (https://5xxrw.csb.app/node_modules/react-router/index.js:266:18)
    at BrowserRouter (https://5xxrw.csb.app/node_modules/react-router-dom/index.js:284:18)
```

The app should navigate back the user to the `Home` page ("/" route) instead of returning the error.

Here is the code for the `AuthenticationRoute`:

```js
function AuthenticationRoute(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  const userProfile = readUserProfileFromLocalStorage();

  return userProfile ? <Navigate replace to="/sign-in" /> : children;
}
```

and here is the code for the `PrivateRoute`:

```js
function PrivateRoute(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  const userProfile = readUserProfileFromLocalStorage();

  return userProfile ? (
    <Dashboard>{children}</Dashboard>
  ) : (
    <Navigate replace to="/sign-in" />
  );
}
```

Here is the playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-auth-private-routes-5xxrw

I did a similar thing using `react-router-dom v5` but didn't return the error. Everything was fine.

**So, what's the solution for this case?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue on your `AuthenticationRoute` component. You are redirecting the user to `/sign-in` when `userProfile` is defined, which causes an infinite loop since its the same page. It should be navigating to `/`

```
function AuthenticationRoute(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  const userProfile = readUserProfileFromLocalStorage();

  return userProfile ? <Navigate replace to="/" /> : children;
}
```